# jQuery map() bug with IE7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dictionary

I have the following jquery code:

```
$('.menubox').children('div').toArray().map(function(n,i){
            return [$(n).children('input').val(),$(n).children('.subs').children('div').toArray().map(function(n,i){ 
                    return [$(n).children('input').val(),$(n).children('.subs').children('div').toArray().map(function(n,i){ 
                            return $(n).children('input').val(); 
                        })];
                })];
        });
```

This is the HTML to go with that:

```
        <td class="menubox">
        <div class="draggable droppable lvl0">
            <input type="hidden" value="-" />
            LBL1
            <div class="subs"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="draggable droppable lvl0">
            <input type="hidden" value="-" />
            LBL2
            <div class="subs">                  
                <div class="draggable droppable lvl1">
                    <input type="hidden" value="3" />
                    <b>LBL2.1</b><span style="display:block;"><a class="deleteItem">verwijder</a></span>
                    <div class="subs"></div>
                </div>                  

                <div class="draggable droppable lvl1">
                    <input type="hidden" value="6" />
                    <b>LBL2.2</b><span style="display:block;"><a class="deleteItem">verwijder</a></span>
                    <div class="subs"></div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

It works fine in chrome but IE throws an error:

> Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

When I remove the map() function, the error is gone. What am I doing wronge here?

Comment: BTW, what is the goal of all this `.map()`ing? I'm guessing there's a much simpler way to get what you want.

Comment: I need to end up with an array with the id's (input.val()) and structure. something like: [['-'],['-',[['5'],['6']]]] given the html above

Comment: As it is right now, the above code returns an array like `[["-",[]],["-",[["3",[]],["6",[]]]]]`, not like the one in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wronge here?

Calling `.toArray()` on a jQuery object. Remove those calls, and add `.get()` after [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) if you want to end up with a vanilla JS array. Note that jQuery's `.map()` callback takes `index, element` while `Array.map`'s callback takes `element, index` so you also need to swap the argument names.

```
var results = $('.menubox').children('div').map(function(i, n)
{
    return [
        $(n).children('input').val(),
        $(n).children('.subs').children('div').map(function(i, n)
        {
            return [
                $(n).children('input').val(),
                $(n).children('.subs').children('div').map(function(i, n)
                {
                    return $(n).children('input').val();
                }).get()
            ];
        }).get()
    ];
}).get();

console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
// ["-",[],"-",["3",[],"6",[]]]
```

This works in Chrome but not IE since Chrome supports [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but (surprise, surprise) IE <9 do not.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5KBdA/

Comment: No worries. You can always come back later when you've got the rep if you feel that strongly about it.

Comment: Call me crazy, but you wrote a solution but then said it still doesn't work in IE8/9.  Was there a workaround for the no-map in IE8/9 problem?  Looks like you can use the jquery version: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/