# Why my jQuery is not working on IE (works fine in Safari, Chrome and FF)?

Tags: jquery, windows, wordpress, internet-explorer

He, there, i've been trying around hours with no clue (i'm using Wordpress), it's very hard to know what's wrong with jQuery. FF and Chrome in Windows/Mac work fine, IE drive me crazy.

I'm using in the header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This is the web where i'm doing the test:

http://newportal.no-ip.org/

This is my JS code:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//Menu
    jQuery("ul.menu").superfish({
            delay       : 100,
            animation   : {opacity:'show',height:'show'},
            //speed     : 10,
            autoArrows  : true, 
            dropShadows : false
        });

//Popup FancyBox
jQuery('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });

jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox(); 

    var thumbnails = 'a:has(img)[hrefjQuery=".jpg"]';
    jQuery(thumbnails).addClass("fancybox").attr("rel","fancybox");


jQuery(".popup").fancybox({
         'width' : '75%',
         'height' : '75%',
         'autoScale' : false,
         'transitionIn' : 'none',
         'transitionOut' : 'none',
         'type' : 'iframe'
     });

//Expand
jQuery('div.moexpander').hide();
    jQuery('a.moexpander').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().next('div.moexpander').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });  

//Slideshow Destacados, Create an array of titles
    var titles = jQuery('#cycle div.item').find("h3").map(function() { return jQuery(this).text(); });
    //Add an unordered list to contain the navigation
    //Invoke the cycle plugin on #cycle
    jQuery('#cycle').before('<ul id="pager" class="sprites bannerBg"></ul>').cycle({
        //Specify options
        fx      :'fade', //Name of transition effect
        speed   : 600,
        delay   : -1200,
        pause   :   1,
        pager   : '#pager',     //Selector for element to use as pager container
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {               //Build the pager
        return '<li><a href="#">' + titles[index] + '</a></li>';
    },
    updateActivePagerLink: function(pager, currSlideIndex) {
        jQuery(pager).find('li').removeClass('active').filter('li:eq('+currSlideIndex+')').addClass('active');
    }
    });
  jQuery('#cycle').hover(function() {
  jQuery('.pause').show();
  }, function() {
        jQuery('.pause').hide();
    });


//Slideshow Voluntariado
    jQuery('#cyclePopular').after('<div id="navPopular">') 
        .cycle({ 
    fx          : 'scrollHorz',
    speed       : 'fast',
    delay   : -1200,
    pause   :   1,  
    pager       : '#navPopular'
    });

//Slideshow Avisos
    jQuery('#cycleAvisos').cycle({ 
    fx          : 'scrollHorz',
    delay   : -4000,
    pause   :   1,
    prev:    '#prev',
    next:    '#next',
    pager       : '#navAvisos',
    after: onAfter
    });
//Make Avisos's Height auto-resizing    
    function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
        var jQueryht = jQuery(this).height();

        //set the container's height to that of the current slide
        jQuery(this).parent().animate({height: jQueryht});
    }

//Make all the block clickable  
jQuery("#link").click(function(){
     window.location=jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
});         

//Add CSS to Sidebar Pages
jQuery('#sidebar-pages').find("li").before("<span class='sprites bulletR left'></span>");



// Tabs
 jQuery.fn.easytabs = function(){
 //Default Action
 jQuery(this).find(".easytabs_content").hide(); //Hide all content
 jQuery(this).find("ul.easytabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
 jQuery(this).find(".easytabs_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
 jQuery(this).find(".easytabs_content li a").before("<span class='sprites bulletR'></span>"); //Show bullets

 //On Click Event
 jQuery("ul.easytabs li").click(function() {
 jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("ul.easytabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
 jQuery(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
 jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".easytabs_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
 var activeTab = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
 jQuery(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
 return false;
 });
};//end function

jQuery("div[class^='easytabs']").easytabs(); //Run function on any div with class name of "easytabs"

// Search animation with IE statements
    var input = jQuery('input#s');
    var divInput = jQuery('div.input');
    var width = divInput.width();
    var outerWidth = divInput.parent().width() - (divInput.outerWidth() - width) - 28;
    var submit = jQuery('#searchSubmit');
    var txt = input.val();

    input.bind('focus', function() {
        if(input.val() === txt) {
            input.val('');
        }
        jQuery(this).animate({color: '#000'}, 300); // text color
        jQuery(this).parent().animate({
            width: outerWidth + 'px',
            backgroundColor: '#fff', // background color
            paddingRight: '43px'
        }, 300, function() {
            if(!(input.val() === '' || input.val() === txt)) {
                if(!(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9)) {
                    submit.fadeIn(300);
                } else {
                    submit.css({display: 'block'});
                }
            }
        }).addClass('focus');
    }).bind('blur', function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({color: '#b4bdc4'}, 300); // text color
        jQuery(this).parent().animate({
            width: width + 'px',
            backgroundColor: '#e8edf1', // background color
            paddingRight: '15px'
        }, 300, function() {
            if(input.val() === '') {
                input.val(txt)
            }
        }).removeClass('focus');
        if(!(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9)) {
            submit.fadeOut(100);
        } else {
            submit.css({display: 'none'});
        }
    }).keyup(function() {
        if(input.val() === '') {
            if(!(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9)) {
                submit.fadeOut(300);
            } else {
                submit.css({display: 'none'});
            }
        } else {
            if(!(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9)) {
                submit.fadeIn(300);
            } else {
                submit.css({display: 'block'});
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I'll really appreciate your help,

H·

Comment: Did you check your console? Are you getting errors? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Which function doesnt't work? All of them?

Comment: What version of jQuery? What version of IE?

Comment: The problem is with IE 10 and the console is not showing up JS problem. That's my worry.

Comment: Can you tell us the exact version of jQuery you're using? This can be important if, say, you're running IE10 in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

I see two method calls that are not well supported (or supported at all) by IE:

- `.hover`
- `.slideToggle`

All of the `toggle` functions have rough/inconsistent cross-browser support. I would try to change this, especially since the `slide` effects actually have some of the highest overhead of all of the jQuery effects, and it is blatantly apparent on slow browsers (like IE - especially the older versions).

As for `.hover`, I suggest that you read up on and use a combination of `.mouseenter`, `.mouseleave`, `.mousein`, and `.mouseout`. I do not recall which, but `.hover` is actually short-hand for two of those, but support for it is rough. One of those sets is based, specifically, on the built in settings for IE, and I do not think it is the one that `.hover` is short-hand for.

**UPDATE 1:**

Based on your feedback, what I would advise is that you search the `.superFish` and `fancybox` plugins' source code to make sure that they do not use `fadeTo` for `opacity`, as that will entirely break your script, and that they use the correct `opacity` manipulation techniques, that are compatible with IE.

**UPDATE 2:**

Your `.map()` method is also wrong. From the rest of your code, I can see that you are trying to create a vanilla JavaScript array, not a jQuery array. As such, you must call `.get()` after `.map()`. I found an [answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6371943/1506793) that further explains this.

**UPDATE 3:**

I hope I am not being silly, but I noticed this line:

```
jQuery('div.moexpander').hide();
```

which you have right before you set up a click handler for `jQuery('div.moexpander')`. The problem is, I do not see another call anywhere to show `jQuery('div.moexpander')`. If I am correct, and you did not show it again after that, the `div.moexpander` element will never be shown and the handler will never be used. I do not know how crucial this is to your code/issue, as I still don't know your symptoms, but this is very probably a bug.

**UPDATE 4:**

Also, so long as we are debugging, you should run through your code and terminate each function declaration with a semi-colon. For example, change:

```
function someFunct() { 
    ..... 
}
```

to

```
function someFunct() { 
    ..... 
};
```

Although this is not required in JavaScript, there are many situations in which this will impact/effect your scripts, and, in some cases, crash them.

To be honest, I do not completely understand why this is the case, but I have encountered situations in which this was the issue, and I believe some of these issues were in IE.

**UPDATE 5:**

If this is still not working, check out [this thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-load-doesnt-work-on-first-call-in-ff3-and-ie-but-works-in-ff3-5) on the jQuery forum, which deals with IE loading issues involving fancyBox.

Comment: May I ask why you think `hover()` and `slideToggle()` are broken on IE? In my experience, they both work perfectly fine on IE from 6 to 10 (jQuery 1.9) or 9 to 10 (jQuery 2.0).

Comment: Let me try your solution. Thank you for reply.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I have not reviewed the updates to `.hover` and `.slideToggle` since for 1.8.3+, since I stopped using them in 1.7.2 and they were not updated (or at least significantly) between that time and 1.8.2. Perhaps new changes were introduced since then, but, especially since the OP did not specify a version, I think it was prudent to point this out. To answer your question directly, all of the `toggle` methods have cross-browser issues, especially in IE. These issues get worse if events are repeated quickly, or if the pages' scripts require a lot of overhead.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Note that `slide` effects have some of the highest overhead of all effects, and the fact that all of the `toggle` methods have extra logic that provides support for the `toggle` aspect, thus making `slideToggle` even more difficult in IE.

Comment: Doesn't work Frédéric Hamidi, also i deleted all that function to see if that was the problem but no.

Comment: @Huroman, this is not my answer, I think you want to address Zachary instead :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I believe that you are correct, but I like this whole thing where if it is wrong it is your answer, but if it is right it is my answer haha :)

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel I'm really working on all your possible solutions and you're very kind, thank you.

Comment: Not a problem, it's what we are here for. :) I would pause what you are doing and quickly make the updates suggested in UPDATE 4, and then make sure that what UPDATE 3 is not your issue. They are the simple cases, and should only take a few minutes.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel I think all the problems were how i (and my client) saw the site (via IP and not by domain or alias), firstable, i'm working on Windows Server with Wordpress installed on it (something new for me because i always work on Apache) and it's odd, if i visit the web via IP, JS wont work but if i visit it via domain, works.

I'll try to debugging tomorrow in order to see how it works on a domain.

Thank you so much and i'll post everything i found.

Comment: That's actually a common happening. It's often prudent to try a new environment if you are stuck on a bug. Good luck, moving forward! :)